# how to install libreoffice on heroku

Tags: heroku

I am trying this http://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/ on heroku which require libreoffice to be installed on heroku to cut docs in to pdfs.
Is there any build pack available for this or how to create a build pack for this

Comment: Tried to create my own buildpack, failed on too many dependencies. :(

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for an answer to this also, so I ended up building my own LibreOffice buildpack: https://github.com/rishihahs/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice

Comment: I just tried this and am facing an issue when invoking the `soffice` bin as per https://github.com/rishihahs/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice/issues/2 any ideas?

Comment: When I use this buildpack I get: `Compiled slug size: 453.7M is too large (max is 300M).`

Comment: @fatuhoku What did you end up doing? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @10101010 You can ask Heroku for a slug size increase

Answer (score 0):

There is a heroku buildpack for this at: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/BlueTeaLondon/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice-for-heroku-18